# com.microsoft.alm.plugin.external.exceptions.ToolAuthenticationException: KEY_TF_AUTH_FAIL

Tags: java, tfvc

I can't update source with Team Foundation (TFVC) in IntelliJ.

```
 com.microsoft.alm.plugin.external.exceptions.ToolAuthenticationException: KEY_TF_AUTH_FAIL
    at com.microsoft.alm.plugin.external.commands.FindWorkspaceCommand.throwIfError(FindWorkspaceCommand.java:140)
    at com.microsoft.alm.plugin.external.commands.FindWorkspaceCommand.parseOutput(FindWorkspaceCommand.java:98)
    at com.microsoft.alm.plugin.external.commands.FindWorkspaceCommand.parseOutput(FindWorkspaceCommand.java:26)
    at com.microsoft.alm.plugin.external.commands.Command$1.completed(Command.java:178)
    at com.microsoft.alm.plugin.external.ToolRunner$ListenerProxy.completed(ToolRunner.java:295)
    at com.microsoft.alm.plugin.external.ToolRunner$ProcessWaiter.run(ToolRunner.java:333)
```

Comment: Have you changed any of your configuration recently? Did this work previously? Looks like this might be related to this issue with server workspaces: https://github.com/microsoft/azure-devops-intellij/issues/256

Answer (score 0):

I continue to get this error. The only way I have been able to resolve it is to clone the project to a new workspace, or edit the workspace and resave without making any changes. The plugin then works for a couple days until I receive the error again. I am using the plugin with JetBrains Rider